# Highcharts not plotting series correctly on secondary axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Hi I am using the Highcharts library to create a bar chart with a cumulative plot line as demonstrated in the jsFiddle below.

[CHART DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akaimo/7s28hh6k/)

I am looking to have the cumulative series represented like the red line in the following image (with cumulative values plotted on the right-most axis):

[SAMPLE OF DESIRED OUTPUT](http://postimg.org/image/7dxyy8la1/)

As you can see the secondary Y Axis is flipped and is displaying the series index value rather than the actual cumuative values.

Here is the current code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null,
            }
        },
        {
        opposite:true,
            title: {
                text: "Cumulative"
            }
    }],
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
    }, {
        name: 'Cumulative',
        xAxis:1,
        type:"spline",
        data: [34, 732, 914, 1973, 4054]
    }
    ]
});
```

How can I correct this in order to plot the series as intended?

Thanks!

Comment: Is 'Cumulative' supposed to be the sum of each category's 1900 and 2008 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is after loading add a new series based on the sum of the 2 series added at creation:

```
    events: {
        load: function () {
            var s1900 = this.series[0].data;
            var s2008 = this.series[1].data;
            var newData = [];
            if (s1900.length == s2008.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < s1900.length; i++) {
                    newData.push(s1900[i].y + s2008[i].y);
                }
            }
            this.addSeries({
                name: 'Cumulative',
                xAxis: 0,
                type: "spline",
                data: newData
            });
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why you want this on the opposite xAxis or why your curve in the linked image you supplied is not really the cumulative unless that is not what you really want. See live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7s28hh6k/2/).

Note you are going to have to handle cases where not all points have a value or if one category is not in both series, etc etc etc.

Revised answer.
Assuming you want to have the same categories on the alternate xAxis and do not want to share the same yAxis you can do:

```
...
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        }, {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            }
        }, {
            min: 0,
            opposite: true,
            reversed: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Cumulative Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            }
        }],
...
```

This sets it up so that you have identical xAxis categories (other ways to do this). See new [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7s28hh6k/6/).

Comment: Thanks appreciate the answer.  This is may be a bad example - I'm only using the population chart to demo the issue taking into account the cumulative values are not actual calculated values, nor will it be used with population.  I would already have the cumulative values passed in array (not from javascript) so it wouldn't have to be calculated in the chart script.  To clarify: yes these could be plotted along the same axis, however, adding the cumulative curve to the real data changes the scale of the axis so it becomes less readable.  This is the reason for keeping them on separate axes.

Comment: A separate `yAxis`, then, is what you need. Not a separate `xAxis`. The `xAxis` you are using is the categories of information you want to know the value of. The `yAxis` contains the values. Here is a modified example with secondary yAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/7s28hh6k/3/

Comment: Yes it seems backwards, even Highcharts retains the same axes names whether it is a BAR or COLUMN chart.  Despite swapping the axes, your demo is still plotting the line vertically according to the top xAxis, but would like to have it on the right yAxis.

Comment: @akaimo, in a bar chart the yAxis is horizontal and the and the xAxis is vertical. So, the "top" yAxis is the "right" one in this case. Change the chart.type to 'column' and you can see that the cumulative curve is using the right yAxis.

Comment: Ok assuming xAxis is the vertical, I need to plot the cumulative line according to the right xAxis.  Sorry I know this is confusing.

Comment: @akaimo, what is the right xAxis? New categories? Same categories as the original xAxis?

Comment: the categories would be the same essentially, but the values different.

Comment: thanks - I think I may have confused it there, the categories are the same but it should display the respective cumulative values on that right xAxis instead of the series names.  What I'm trying to do is exactly the red line in the image only with the right xAxis inverted with zero at the bottom.

Comment: I am utterly confused by what you are asking for now. Can you put up a real example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've updated the demo and code in my original question - the image of desired output is still relevant.  Cumulative series is already in the chart code so it does not need to be generated, only moved to the right side axis.

Comment: I see your updated code. Your values, in this context cannot be on the "right" xAxis - those are categories (Africa, Europe, etc). See http://jsfiddle.net/7s28hh6k/8/. You keep one xAxis and then use 2 yAxis. It is not advised to have, in a single chart, both categories (things to measure) and value scale (the measured value of the thing) to be on  the same axis.

Comment: The categories (aka continents) in this case I want to keep left.  I'm looking for the right axis to display a number range (like 0 to 10k) fitting the cumulative series high and low values.  Right now it's only showing the corresponding array key

Comment: Because you can't do that.

Comment: Honestly, I'm lost in this topic. Can't we just use categories on second xAxis, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7s28hh6k/9/ ? Demo-image has some strange red line on it - does that line matter?

Comment: Yes we can use the categories on that axis as you have shown.  This is what I'm looking for but it would duplicate the series and not readily handle dynamic data when the range changes.  I have essentially acquiesced to the idea that this cannot be done without a super hacky approach.